# Is there a soft keyboard for the HTC Droid Incredible that learns word combinations?

Tags: keyboard

A friend of mine was talking about a soft keyboard replacement for the HTC Droid Incredible and I believe that he mentioned one of the features was that it not only suggested words, but it would "learn" word combinations and suggest not only the current word, but the next word in the sentence. However, I've forgotten the name of the keyboard. Does anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it [Swiftkey](http://www.market4android.com/swiftkey-predictive-and-accurate-keyboard.php)?

> SwiftKey brings the future of text entry to smartphones. It uses TouchType’s breakthrough Fluency™ technology to predict the next word you want to type, before you even press a key.
>   [...]
>   SwiftKey doesn’t just predict regular words – it learns as you type and remembers how you write. As words and sentences are chosen over time, its Fluency™ engine creates a dynamic understanding of your writing style to boost the accuracy, fluency and speed of prediction.

Comment: Checking out the site now...at first glance, that might be it.

Comment: Yep. That's it. And it appears it's available, too. When I was first told about it, it was in a private beta.